# Backslashing does not work to send a bell via the echo command

Tags: bash, echo, escape-characters

The `echo` command doesn't want to interpret backlash escapes (with -e option attached). For example, I want it to ring a bell with:
`echo -e \a`

Nothing happens, except it prints:
`a`
or
`\a`

How to turn on interpreting or how to fix it?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `echo -e \a` the `\` in front of the `a` will be stripped off from the argument to `echo` by the shell before `echo` is called.  It is exactly equivalent to

```
echo -e 'a'
```

For `echo` to receive `\a` as backslash-followed-by-a, the `\` has to be passed as is to `echo`.  This is done either through

```
echo -e '\a'
```

or

```
echo -e \\a
```

If this will actually produce an audible or visible bell may depend on other settings.

Comment: `~/.inputrc` is to configure `readline`, it doesn't affect the terminal behaviour when you send a BEL character to it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hmm... I wonder why I don't get any bells then. Is it because I run `tmux`? But readline would at least control the shell's bells?

Comment: Yes, readline's `bell-style` would control whether readline sends a `\a` (BEL) or a visual bell escape sequence or nothing to the terminal when it wants to notify the user.

Comment: See also [Why Ctrl+G doesn't produce a beep?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/401156)

Answer (score 3):

You need to protect the `\` from being interpreted by the shell. Try this:

```
echo -e '\a'
```

or

```
echo -e \\a
```